# WooCommerce: List Variations Available

Tags: woocommerce, catalog, product-variations

I'm trying to display the variations of a products in the category page, something like

"Product Image"

"Product Title"

**from $107 - $ 200** (I got this done)

**Available in: 5lb / 10lb / 20lb** (I'm trying to achieve this)

I read online and found this function but i couldn't get it to work, keep saying function does not exist.

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Price
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product;
?>

<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php

**if ($product->get_variation_attributes(size)) {
echo $product->get_variation_attributes(size);
}**

?>
```

What i wish to achieve is fairly simple, I just need to let customers know that there are different bag size of my products available, however a simple "From $100" as per custom woocommerce template does not let novice online shopper know that means there are other variations.

I've added Size attribute under each of my variation products like 5KG, 6KG, 7Lb, and hope to display them in front page in red.

I do not need sophiscated solutions like drop down list or whatsoever, just plain display if variation is available.

Hope Someone can point me to some direction.

Update: This is my current solution, however, If i can list down the variation available it will be a bonus.

```
 if ( $product->max_variation_price && $product->max_variation_price !== $product->min_variation_price ) {

echo "<span style='font-size:75%; color: red; display: block;'>Available in Various Sizes</span>";
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to create a plugin for a similar (if not identical) problem. I basically want to display all variants for a variable product in one go, with a "add to cart" and quantity box for each. This differs from the WooCommerce approach of hiding all the variations behind drop-down lists. For wholesale supplies, this is a very necessary thing, otherwise bulk orders become very difficult to place. Is this anything like what you are aiming to do? I most likely will have some development time available to do this.

Comment: @Jason This would be awesome. Please let me know if/when you get the plugin created.